# Perl - returning two array references from a subroutine, wish to process only the first

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, subroutine

Syntactically, why doesn't the following code work? Suppose mySub() is a subroutine which returns two array references:

```
...
my @list1 = @{${mySub()}[0]};
my @list2 = @{${mySub()}[1]};
...

sub mySub{
    ...
    return \@array1, \@array2;
}
```

(Never mind the fact that I'm running this sub twice.) To my understanding, the curly braces tell perl that I want the output to be interpreted as an array, from which I extract the first (second) value and dereference it into an array.

Comment: If you had a real array `@a` (which is what the call to `mySub` returns (a list, actually) how would you extract an element?

Comment: This is what I tried to do above: ${mySub()}[0]. Is that not correct?

Comment: Look closely - you wrapped that in another `@{...}`

Comment: Ah, yes, but that is because I in fact want ${mySub()}[0] to be an array reference, and I would like to get at the array it refers to, so I dereference again, and store the result in @list1.

Comment: @JimGarrison: there is a vast difference between returning a list and returning an array; mySub does *not* return an array or array reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your:

```
@{${mySub()}[1]}
```

is placing the mySub() in a `${ ... }[ ... ]`, which expects an array reference to look up an element of, as if you had returned `[ \@array1, \@array2 ]` from your subroutine.  You can find some helpful hints to think about how to deal with data structure references at http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference.

In your case, you want to use a list slice, not an array element lookup, to get the arrayref you want to then dereference:

```
@{ ( mySub() )[1] }
```